# Outputting multiple lists/tables from rmarkdown

Tags: r

I have one big dataset (23 columns and >20k rows) which is a list of people from different locations. I want to generate multiple separate formatted reports each containing people from same location using R Markdown. When I knit to PDF, I am getting it but using the loop to get the separated reports, I am getting the error "*! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'*".

Here is the rmarkdown formatting lines

```
knitr::kable(Lists, "latex",booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down")) %>%
  column_spec(11:23, width = "10em") %>% 
  row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "black")
```

Here is the loop line

```
for (Sector in Lists){
  rmarkdown::render(input = "C:/Downloads/lists.Rmd", 
                    output_format = "pdf_document")
  }
```

I have reviewed all questions asked on this subject but all of them didn't help (spent an entire day reviewing them, maybe it's because I am new to markdown). Any help to understand why this error is coming up or any other way I can accomplish this task is much appreciated.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lXc0OliZVqRVn0Zf5Ht578w9_mEbS32J/view?usp=sharing) is the link to the sample of the Lists dataset.

Comment: Could you please shows us your YAML header?

Comment: Here it is   `---
title: "Clients Lists"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---`

Comment: @M.A. would you take a look again?

Comment: I think this LaTeX error probably results from some R function setting `H` as the position argument in a float environment (which is invalid). It's hard to diagnose without the rmarkdown file. Could you edit your question and add a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which gives the same error?